# How to match against a list/array in regrex in plsql?

Tags: python, regex, plsql

I have some code in plsql like this

```
regexp_matches(source_string, pattern)
```

I want to match the source string against a list say a list of currency symbols. I already have that list in my python code, i want the above function to return a match if the source starts with any of the currency symbols (not multiple symbols). So "$345" should match while as "abc345" and "$$230"should not.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Using regex's you can achieve this with: `^\$\d+$`

Breakdown: 
`^...$` - matches anything in between (...) from line start (^) to line end ($), you need this to avoid matching `$$450` (line starts with 2 $ instead of 1)

           `\$` - literal dollar symbol (has to be escaped)

 `\d` - any number from 0 to 9

 `\d+` - any number from 0 to 9 repeated at least once (eg. 8, 8735, but not nothing)

Link to test and play around: https://regex101.com/r/c3YgQO/1

---

Since there was more info added in the comments, here is an update:

This regex: `^(-?([€$]\d+|\d+%))$` seems to be what you are looking for.

Breakdown:

`-?` - matches `-` once or not at all, making it optional

`(...|\d+%)` - matches `...` or `\d+%`

`\d+%` - matches at least one number followed by one percent symbol (`%`)

New test link: https://regex101.com/r/NBzaG1/1

To also match numbers with decimal point you can replace `\d+` with: `\d+(\.\d)?\d*`

Comment: what about other currency symbols? You code will work for only dollar.

Comment: You can add multiple currency symbols with: `^[$€¥]\d+$`
Notice that you dont need to escape any of the symbols in between `[` and `]`.
I suggest getting a list of currency symbols and chaining them together in a string to use this: `pattern = '^[' + your_currency_symbols_string + ']\d+$'`

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar do you also want to match amounts with a decimal point, e.g. $3.50, or amounts with a thousands separator, e.g. $2,000,000? What about strings that end in a currency, e.g. "Give me $100"?

Comment: Also some countries use their currency symbol after the number, like: 350€ instead of €350.

Comment: is there wayout to mention list of the currency symbols instead writing hardcode values ... like this [currencySymbolList] and not [$€¥....]

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker yes i want to match amounts with a decimal point. Basically i have a string, this string can have currency symbol, percentage or a minus sign, i want to get the number with sign(if negative) if it a valid number. Valid here means if has a single - in front of the number, or a single currency symbol or a percentage symbol at the end